# The discriminating power of experienced listeners

Tags: voice, ear-training, tone, frequency, psychoacoustics

Consider a choir of *n* singers who [sing the same tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0S7QabzsGG8) in almost perfect [**unison**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison).

When asked how many singers they do hear, test persons may say:

- don't know
- more than 3, 5, 10, ...
- 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...

At the heart of discriminating and thus counting singers just by listening lies the ability to distinguish voices by timbres, i.e. to analyse a highly complex frequency spectrum. Experienced listeners will typically perform better than unexperienced ones. Disturbing effects of reverb and so on must be taken into consideration (and possibly be minimized or even eliminated).

Are there reported "world records" like

> X was able to reliably tell if there were 3, 4, 5 up to 12 singers
>   singing?

Is there scientific literature on this topic?

---

You may want to compare these questions to this seemingly more natural one:

> Let *n* voices play *n* **different** tunes (as in a
>   big band or any kind of orchestra) - how many voices can be
>   distinguished (by the most experienced listeners)?

Comment: I'm unaware of any such literature, and it's hard to imagine any way of getting valid results, because there are so many variables that are not controlled.  No group of singers sings in perfect unison, and every group varies from perfect unison in different ways.  Unless you set up a contest where there is only one recording to judge from, you will get different results every time.

Comment: I think when 2 or more voices sing in perfect unison ... the result should  be one single  voice with an new timbre: the sum of all formantes.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: Is this so? In this case, the unison should be only *almost* perfect. (I slightly changed the question.)

Comment: This is just an assumption! But I think: If John and Paul and George sang unisono I hear a mix of them and supposed I know them each one I could probably identify the one or the other or I can say when I miss one of them. Before I‘d ask how many voices  there are I would ask which variables can identified.

Comment: "At the heart of discriminating and thus counting singers just by listening lies the ability to distinguish voices by timbres" -- where is this assumption coming from? // The ability to estimate the number of performers depends on many additional variables.  How are you going to control for all of them?

Comment: @aparente001: You are right, it was just a guess, and of course the ability to discriminate different voices doesn't rely solely on the ability to distinguish voices by timbres - only among other things (but nevertheless). Could you (and maybe Albrecht Hügli?) give some specific examples of  additional variables? To my mind come: intonation, exact timing (synchrony), pronounciation (when text is sung).

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: Maybe you want to have a look at this [follow-up question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/an-experiment-concerning-the-distinction-of-voices).

Comment: @aparente001: Maybe you want to have a look at this [follow-up question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/an-experiment-concerning-the-distinction-of-voices).

Comment: "What variables are involved?" would be a Question, not appropriate for a comment chain.  And I think it would be a worthwhile question.

Comment: @aparente001:  Why wouldn't this other question be closed - as off-topic or opinion-based?

Comment: If singers sing in perfect unison, I see no possibility of telling the number of singers involved (without pre-knowledge). You need to sing them in different pitches in order to be able to assign different parts of the spectrum to individual singers.